# Call other Sonar API in Java custom plugins (SonarQube 6.3.1)

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, sonarqube6.3

I am developing a custom plugin to launch an analysis from the SonarQube's web interface. So I have implemented a `WebService` class with a `Controller` and an `Action`.

I would like to call in the handler of this action the other APIs in order to create a project ans set the quality profiles (with parameter given in json).

I manage to call them from my JS client following the official guide but there is nothing concerning server side.

I would like to know how to call those APIs from Java server side with **SonarQube 6.3.1**.

Comment: for understand, you want your server sonarqube instance run an analysis ?

Comment: Yes, it is my final goal but my problem is just to know how properly reuse sonarqube api to create a project and set quality profile in Java.

Comment: look at  WsClient wsClient = WsClientFactories.getLocal()
                .newClient(request.localConnector()); with wsClient you can access a lot of sonarqube services.